# AngularJs ng-repeat : - listing element only for values of last JSON object instead of complete JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

when i send $http request ,i get collection of object as JSON array as a response,now i want to use object values in data-value attr of  tag using ng-repeat for each object in response array,but it creates the element based on last object value.what can be the problem?and how can i resolve it???

Here is my Html code:

```
<table ng-controller="GetObject">

  <tr ng-repeat="item in ObjectList">
    <td>{{item.status | lowercase}}
     <div ng-if="item.status != 'active'" class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn">Activate Via</button>
        <div ng-repeat="s in SList" class="dropdown-content">
         <a class='activation' href='javascript:void(0)' data-value='active.php?id={{s.id}}&status=active&id={{item.id}}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#activation'>{{server.server_name}}</a>



            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>{{item.type}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my angular code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('GetObject', function($scope,$http) {

  $http({
    method : "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url : "getobjlist.php"
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.ObjectList = response.data;

    alert("success"+$scope.ObjectList );

      $http({
    method : "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url : "getlist.php"
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {

    $scope.SList = response.data;
    alert("success"+$scope.SList);
}, function myError(response) {
    alert(response.statusText);
});

}, function myError(response) {
    alert(response.statusText);
});


});
```

i am getting everything fine in response but the problem is :

```
       <div ng-repeat="s in SList" class="dropdown-content">
         <a class='activation' href='javascript:void(0)' data-value='active.php?id={{s.id}}&status=active&id={{item.id}}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#activation'>{{s.name}}</a>



            </div>
        </div>
```

create the dropdown-content only for the last 's' in 'SList'

Comment: {{ server.server_name }} or {{ s.server_name }} ???

Comment: s.server_name ,but its not the issue

Comment: try 'track by $index' >> ng-repeat="s in SList track by $index"

Comment: Also, try to change the order of HTTP calls. First, call to get sList data and later ObjectList data